# Excel (Dependent) Data Validation Across three seperate fields

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, data-validation

I am looking to create a data validation formula which will allow me to check against multiple fields.

Amount Claimed, Amount Approved, Amount Paid.

The Amount Claimed is first entered. From there, the amount Approved is entered. This can be less than or equal to the claimed amount.

The amount paid is then entered. This again can be less than or equal to the amount Approved.

I noticed in my initial review of the sheet, I could have an amount claimed, and an amount paid input without the approved input. This caused a hiccup in my sheet.

I need a dependent data validation, right? I am not sure how to set it up that I can't have a Paid entry  without the Approved entry.

Hopefully this is clear enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you go to set up the data validation, you want to go to

Allow: **whole number** and

Data: **less than or equal to**.

Put the Maximum: as `=A1` or whatever cell the first number is in.

The just do the same for the C1, but reference `=B1` as the maximum

[image]

[image]

Comment: But then, i Could have 123 Claimed, 76 Approved, and 89 paid, and it also doesn't allow for dollars and cents.  I need it to validate across both the claimed and the approved fields in the paid field.

Comment: @GrntsMng No, for the paid, you just do the same thing, but reference the cell that has the approved validation on it.

Comment: what about this kind of instance where we have received a payment but not the approval sheet yet? Sometimes this occurs because of ACH transactions and mail delays.

Claimed, 123 - Approved NO ENTRY - Paid 500. This shouldn't happen, but the idea is to try to limit input errors from the start.

Comment: @GrntsMng you said it yourself, you don't want paid to be larger than approved, even if it does happen. That's more of a process issue than a tool issue. If you really want, then change the `=B1` to `=B1+n` where `n` is how many you think will be exceptions to the rule. Perhaps don't close out invoices where payment is received but no approval has been received, you should be matching the payment amount to the approved amount to detect fraud.

Comment: Yeah, I know where you're coming from. I do appreciate the help, though!

Comment: You might instead restrict paid to the maximum of claimed, but set up some conditional formatting to flag any paid that's greater than approved? @GrntsMng

Comment: The process is related to insurance. essentially, we bill a carrier, they send us the remittance detailing any approved or declined amounts, sends us a remittance advice detailing the approved amounts, and sometimes we receive the payment before the approval sheets. 

The idea was to limit the reporting to at least the billed amounts until the approval sheets come in, but yea, it shouldn't ever happen that way anyway.

Comment: Nice idea with the Conditional Formatting!

I set it up so that the field becomes red if the Approved amount is less than the Paid amount. Easy fix and the Data Validations remain. We'll see if there's any hiccup with that ever.